# Migrating magento shop

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, e-commerce, magento-1.9

I have an e-commerce site with magento 1.7 on a remote server. I desired to change my site design and upgrade magento version to 1.9. I downloaded magento 1.9 and a template and run it on the localhost. I did a lot of changes in design, and it is kind of ready to be uploaded to the remote server. But I don't know how migrate a database from my old site on magento 1.7 to a new one on localhost and also setup all settings as they are on my old site.

Comment: This question belongs to Magento site. See this question https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/21761/magento-upgrade-from-1-7-to-1-9

Comment: Yes, it can probably work, but I don't want to upgrade my old site. I will just delete it. I need to move base settings from my old site(preferences and images) and database to my new site. Because I don't want to create a  new database and the site map from the scratch.

Comment: I just suggest you to simple process of upgrading magneto that is by magneto connect.  check this https://kb.magenting.com/content/5/95/en/upgrade-magento-via-magento-connect.html

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, but if I update my old site to Magento to 1.9 in production, how can I setup new design on it? I'll need to setup template and then customized it again from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Migration between 1.7 to 1.9 is not the easiest things if you are not acknowledge about magento coding structure. 
Please try below process at your local server. 
Process : 
1. Create a database dump for your 1.7 magento store at your local server. 
2. Download zip for 1.9 then just extract it at your local server. 
3. Now try to install by pointing to the old DB. 
4. Magento will automatically migrate your current db by 1.9 structure. 
5. Now go to the old server's app/code/local directory and try to locate all of the local modules and their files then just migrate it with new magento instalation. As we have alreday used old database so we don't need to take care about any tables regarding any module. 
6. Then by following same concept migrate theme files from old server to new server.  Same for here automatically theme will be assigned as we have taken old database. 
7. Also try to follow same for community module
Thanks.